# Why is the training result of my vitgan code always noisy?

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

I used the code with the highest number of stars searching for vitgan on GitHub. This code ran for 18 hours on my 3090, trained 100 times, and generated images full of irregular noise.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LqN0.png)
Why the hell is it? Which parameter is incorrect?
I am really exhausted. It seems that this code cannot run at all.

I hope someone can tell me what's wrong with this code and how to complete the training.
Besides, I would like to know if anyone has successfully run vitgan's code?

Comment: You are asking us to tell you what is wrong with the code, without actually showing the code, so it is impossible.

Comment: This is the GitHub URL for the code. https://github.com/wilile26811249/ViTGAN I don't know exactly where the code went wrong. I feel like there's a problem with both the vit model and the gan.

Comment: This is the GitHub URL for the code. https://github.com/wilile26811249/ViTGAN I don't know exactly where the code went wrong. I feel like there's a problem with both the vit model and the gan.

Comment: The vitgan code I searched for on GitHub is somewhat problematic, and I am a beginner. Can you provide a vitgan code that can be trained smoothly, Doctor?

Comment: ([IBM 3090](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_3090)!?)

Comment: @greybeard hehe

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Vision transformers are notoriously difficult to train, especially so for high quality vision transformers. Stable Diffusion supposedly took 79,000 hours to train. From an article called [Training a Vision Transformer from scratch in less than 24 hours with 1 GPU (2022)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.05187.pdf):

> For example, training a small vision Transformer (ViT)
> like DeiT-S takes about **3 days on 4 GPUs**

Also, from the [arxiv article on the github page](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.04589v1.pdf):

> The GAN models are notorious for unstable training dynamics.

Are your training and verification losses steadily decreasing together? It might take you quite a while, maybe a week, maybe a month, maybe never depending on the quantity and quality of your dataset. Hang in there!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try my best to debug the code again.

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problem as you. I tried many solutions, such as using single-head attention, or reducing the number of blocks, or removing residual connections, and finally I found the sloution is to remove the MLP in the transformer block. From the essence, the purpose of the MLP layer is to transform the attention matrix into a tensor shape that combines your tasks through full connection, such as classification problems or target detection problems, but in order to generate images, a fully connected layer is not required in essence, and the multi-head self-attention tensor can be directly used as image generation.
Since MLP is removed, the output is no longer noise. It is also recommended that you do not use open source modules directly, and try to write the network manually by yourself.